# Installshield Limited Edition refuses to add Extended WPF Toolkit assemblies

Tags: c#, wpf, installshield

I have had the pleasure of using ISLE and its now got to the point where I have to post a question on SO. Ohh the headache.

I have tried added the Extended WPF Tookit via nuget and manually to my application but with no luck getting ISLE to include these assemblies when it builds the installer. I have done a dependency scan in ISLE and in both scenario the dependencies are present.

I am using a TeamCity (v8.1.1) build server to automate the build. Everything works fine except that it will not include the above mentioned assemblies in the package.

How do I solve this problem?

**Update #1**

With some more research it seems that ISLE on the dev. box picked up a wrong version of log4net.dll while the build server found the correct version.

**Resolution** - Cleared all log4net.dll found in the "%temp%\Temporary asp.net files" folder.

Comment: The file `settings.xml` in the `InstallShield\Support\0409` folder can be used to block various Temporary ASP.Net files. It looks like this hasn't been kept up to date with the versions of .NET that have been released. Be careful to to keep the file formatted correctly if you update it (save a backup!).

Answer (score 1):

You solve the problem by turning off dependency scanning and take responsibility for knowing what your applications needs to run and what the best way for deploying it.  Dynamic installation authoring has never fully worked and it never will.    When you take into consideration all the different kinds of apps and the way they take their dependencies it becomes obvious.

The easy button is an illusion.

Comment: I am simply using assembly references an taking into consideration build order I think it should be a simply task. Nothing complication or special. ISLE finds all other references manual and nuget. I may well have to do as suggested however I would prefer not to. I would want to have reflect every single application in my installer.

Comment: While I do appreciate the answer the last point I cannot agree as visual studio does this kinda thing all the time. Just look at the Publish feature. And visual studio has never got it wrong for me. If it ever did it would lose many users to PHP.

Comment: One of these days I'm going to create a blog post where I link to 50 questions on StackOverflow where someone didn't agree with me and then 6 months later they finally accepted the answer and left a comment thanking me.   Sorry, I'm only speaking from 18 years of experience writing over a thousand installers.

Comment: Well Chris your answer may be the only available solution because of the fact that ISLE is fundamentally broken however "easy button is an illusion" is wrong because VS compile and run, VS publish & MS Deploy all find the correct dependencies. Also the previous Windows Installer did the job. Why doesn't ISLE? To solve the problem I added manual references that were missing but did not turn off dependency scanning.

Comment: The "previous Windows Installer" doesn't exist.  You are referring to Visual Studio Setup and Deployment projects which create Windows Installer databases.  I can speak from experience that it does not always work either and that when it doesn't you have to fight like hell to tell it to stop "helping" you.   Look up my email and ping me.  I'd love to have an in depth conversation with you about all of this.

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of why ISLE has these inconsistency and obvious logic problems however I have resolved my  issue, albeit the solution is shaky.

**Issue #1**

Firstly I encountered a XamlParseException due to a TypedInitializationException. An assembly could not be loaded and that assembly was noted in the Exception which turned out to be log4net. The log4net assembly was in the folder however it was the wrong version.

Somehow ISLE found an older version of this assembly in the "%temp%\ASP.NET Temporary files" folder and used that in the package. **Clear all these files and give ISLE no choice but to use the assembly you have provided. NOTE: Don't get gungho and delete the culprit assembly if found in the folder of one or more of your installed applications - it just might stop working**.

**Issue #2**

I realized that not only were the **Extended WPF Toolkit** but the output of a dependent **console application** was missing from the install directory.

*You would expect ISLE to find all dependencies however it doesn't*.

Based on the advice provided by @@Christopher Painter I added the primary output of the console application dependency manually. I expected this to solve the console dependency issue however it turned out to solve both.

*Now does ISLE break internally if the one of the dependencies is unavailable, locked, or some exception occurred while adding to the output causing it to stop at that point and not add any more dependencies. Who knows, but I am sure there are some flaws within ISLE **Microsoft if you are going to ship a 3rd party and only a 3rd party installer ensure that it works properly first***.

**Update #1**

Running the build a second time on the TeamCity server resulted in the Extended WPF Toolkit not being added again. So it seems again the ISLE installer is really shaky.

**Issue #3**

Another option to solve the missing Extended WPF Toolkit assemblies would have been to add then explicitly as dependencies. ISLE however adds a explicit rather than relative path location to these files meaning that you need to recreate the folder structure on your build server (not good).

If anyone has a better solution I would love to hear it. This request also goes out to Flexera Software and hopefully the answer is not to upgrade to the PRO version or pay for support.

Comment: I've given you the better answer. Setup development is development.  Development is requirements, design, construction, testing.  Dependency analysis is requirements 101. Once you know your dependencies you decide how to deploy them: prereq redistributable, merge module, private deployment, GAC, common location.  This is design 101.  No tool will ever make these decisions better then an experienced software developer who knows his code.  It only works in 80% of the time and then fails miserably.  InstallShield should have never tried but they did but inexperienced developers ask for it.

Comment: You might want to notice that I'm the #1 contributor on InstallShield, Windows Installer and related tags.  That I have over 5000 posts on the InstallShield community forum and hundreds of blog posts over 10 years. I love to provide InstallShield support to fellow developers and I'm able to give unbiased answers. InstallShield technical support would not be able to tell you their feature doesn't always work and that you shouldn't even use it.

Comment: I cannot agree with this. Sometimes its not a matter of experience its simply the developer might prefer to use his time elsewhere. Also are you telling me MS Deploy and VS Publish for web apps was a vain attempt and we should deploy the web apps ourselves? The previous VS installer works. I would accept that the statement ISLE has fundamental bugs but not that its not possible to be able to create a good installer that auto detects dependencies.

Comment: Believe what you'd like. There's an old saying... you don't know what you don't know.

Comment: Checkout this old thread: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Detection-of-run-time-DLLs-td6369106.html

Comment: We (the developers of InstallShield) prefer manually handling dependencies, much like we try to avoid frills like dynamic file links in .msi projects. These tools can be good for rapid prototyping or one-offs, but do not give the feedback necessary to inform you proactively when things go sideways.